# OAuth2 redirect from Coinbase resets and requests authorization again

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, oauth

I'm currently working on an application that would rely on connecting with Coinbase and am relying on OAuth2 for authorization.

After reading and watching tutorials on implementing it via Spring, I'm able to open the authorization request page for Coinbase but cannot redirect to retrieve the token. When it redirects, it goes to the same port (localhost:8080) that is used to establish authorization. Whereas in other tutorials I've seen the application handle this properly and continue, the application instead launches the authorization page again.

What I'm wondering is how is Spring supposed to retrieve the token/code once the redirect occurs? If I change the redirect to something besides the url used to start authorization (8080 to some other number), then I see the url containing the code in my browser, but my application can't programmatically use it (unless I copy paste but this would be improper). If the redirect is 8080 then, it starts the process all over again and I can't use the code that was passed. It's probable a simple error but I appreciate any feedback as I'm still new to this.

```
security.oauth2.client.clientId=[redacted]
security.oauth2.client.clientSecret=[redacted]
security.oauth2.client.scope=wallet:accounts:read
security.oauth2.client.accessTokenUri=http://www.coinbase.com/oauth/token
security.oauth2.client.userAuthorizationUri=https://www.coinbase.com/oauth/authorize
security.oauth2.resource.userInfoUri=https://www.coinbase.com/oauth/authorize
security.oauth2.resource.preferTokenInfo=true
security.oauth2.client.pre-established-redirect-uri=http://127.0.0.1:8080
security.oauth2.client.registered-redirect-uri=http://127.0.0.1:8080
security.oauth2.client.use-current-uri=false
```

Comment: It looks like you are using the old oauth library from spring-security-oauth. This is deprecated and you should move on to use spring security's built-in oauth library. See here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Migration-Guide

Comment: As to your problem: Do you have any logs available? Maybe you get an unauthorized 401? But only wild guessing...